# General topological space

Tags: general-topology

1. Find a topological space $X$ so that $X$ and $X*X$ are homeomorphic

What I have done is that if I set $X=N$, and give discrete topology. Is $N$ and $N*N$ can be homeomorphic when it is given discrete topology?

1. suppose $X$ is the union of two disjoint open sets. If $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X, Y$ is also the union of two disjoint, open sets.

What I have done is that let $f:Y \to X$ such that $X=A\cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ is open and disjoint and $Y=f^{-1}(X)=f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$ and cuz $f$ is continuous. So, I think I know the solution of this problem.. but I don't know the following problem

1. Using these two problems, show that the line and plane are not homeomorphic..

What I have thought is that if plane and line are homeomorphic, so are the line except $0$ and the plane except $(0,0)$ and line except $0$ can be expressed as the union of two distinct open intervals. So by the previous problem, the plane except $(0,0)$ should be the form of union of two disjoint open sets. and I don't know how to prove that there is no way that plane except $(0,0)$ can be expressed as the union of two disjoint open sets.

If you help me solve these $3$ problems, I will be so happy.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), you can show that two discrete topological spaces are homeomorphic iff they have the same cardinality (any function is continuous for discrete topology). For (2), it is correct. For (3), you have a good idea: to conclude, use connectedness.

Answer (score 1):

For (1) many other examples also work, but are harder to prove correct ($\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{P}$ (=$\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, the irrationals), $C$ (the standard Cantor set in the unit interval, this is e.g. because it is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology). But the discrete (or indiscrete) space does work, if it is infinite.

(2) seems OK, though you should say something about the inverse images being disjoint as well.

For (3) you need that the plane minus a point is connected (so cannot be written as a disjoint union of two open non-empty subsets: this should follow from whatever your definition of connectedness is). To see this connectedness, going via path-connectedness seems easiest.